# i need some help in html css our services page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a service page in html, CSS but I am facing a problem I don't know how to fix this problem

[image]

this is fixed image I want look like this

[image]

```css
  * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  font-family: 'raleway';
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #fafafa;
}

.wrapper h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 25px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.content-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1000px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.card {
  min-height: 220px;
  width: 320px;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 10px 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card i {
  margin: 20px;
  color: #ff5724;
}

.card h2 {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

.card p {
  color: #6c757d;
  text-align: center;
}

.card:hover {}

.card:hover i,
.card:hover p {
  color: #fff
}

.card:hover h2 {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}

.card:nth-child(1):hover {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 28, 8, 0, 7) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 82, 0, 7) 100%), url('file:///E:/Html%20Web%20Design%20Codes/The%20Coffee%20Store/ourservices.html');
  background-size: cover;
}

.card:nth-child(2):hover {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 28, 8, 0, 7) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 82, 0, 7) 100%), url('file:///E:/Html%20Web%20Design%20Codes/The%20Coffee%20Store/ourservices.html');
  background-size: cover;
}

.card:nth-child(3):hover {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 28, 8, 0, 7) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 82, 0, 7) 100%), url('file:///E:/Html%20Web%20Design%20Codes/The%20Coffee%20Store/ourservices.html');
  background-size: cover;
}

.card:nth-child(4):hover {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 28, 8, 0, 7) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 82, 0, 7) 100%), url('file:///E:/Html%20Web%20Design%20Codes/The%20Coffee%20Store/ourservices.html');
  background-size: cover;
}

.card:nth-child(5):hover {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 28, 8, 0, 7) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 82, 0, 7) 100%), url('file:///E:/Html%20Web%20Design%20Codes/The%20Coffee%20Store/ourservices.html');
  background-size: cover;
}

.card:nth-child(6):hover {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 28, 8, 0, 7) 0%, rgba(255, 0, 82, 0, 7) 100%), url('file:///E:/Html%20Web%20Design%20Codes/The%20Coffee%20Store/my%20color.png');
  background-size: cover;
  /***Responsive****/
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    .wrapper {
      padding:25px;
    }
    .wrapper h1 {
      font-size: 2.5em;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
    .content-box {
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .card {
      min-width: 300px;
      margin: 10px auto;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Our Services</title>
  <!----External Css File---->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ourservices.css">
  <!----Boxicon font css ---->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1> Our Services </h1>
    <p>Aside from a love of that sweet java, this, Jack Wilson, owner of Radio Bistro </p>
    <div class="content-box">
      <div class="card">
        <i class="bx bx-laptop bx-md"></i>
        <h2>Web App Development</h2>
        <p>
          Need help getting started? Check out our business plan templates for guidance. They’re free real-world examples
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="bx bx-line-chart bx-md"></i>
        <h2>24/7 Call Center Services</h2>
        <p>
          Need help getting started? Check out our business plan templates for guidance. They’re free real-world examples
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="bx bx-mail-send bx-md"></i>
        <h2>Soical Media Marketing</h2>
        <p>
          Need help getting started? Check out our business plan templates for guidance. They’re free real-world examples
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="bx bx-bar-chart-alt bx-md"></i>
        <h2>Corporate Business </h2>
        <p>
          Need help getting started? Check out our business plan templates for guidance. They’re free real-world examples
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="bx bx-paint bx-md"></i>
        <h2>Creative Consultancy</h2>
        <p>
          Need help getting started? Check out our business plan templates for guidance. They’re free real-world examples
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <i class="bx bx-bar-chart-alt bx-md"></i>
        <h2>Marketing Services</h2>
        <p>
          Need help getting started? Check out our business plan templates for guidance. They’re free real-world examples
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

please fix this issue and please tell me how i can fix this

Comment: Try with wrapping three div in one div and make the add `display:flex` to main div

Comment: `.card` is a son of wrapper, adn wrapper has `flex-directon: column`. try to add your card divs into a flex container with `flex-direction:row `

Comment: You closed `<div class="content-box">` too early  - it shoud be closed at the end of the page - and missed a `</div>` on one card. voting to close as typo - I fixed your code in the snippet

Answer (score -1):

Try This :
**css**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper{
    font-family: 'raleway';
    display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #fafafa;
}

.wrapper h1{
    
    font-size: 3em; 
    margin: 25px 0;
    text-align: center;  
    font-weight: 500;
}

.content-box{
    
     display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.card{
    min-height: 220px;
    width:320px;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 10px 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    
    

}


.card i{
margin: 20px;
color :#ff5724;

}


.card h2{
margin-bottom: 12px;
font-weight: 400;
text-align: center;


}


.card p{
    color: #6c757d;
    text-align: center;
    
    
    
}
.card:hover{
    
    
}

.card:hover i,
.card:hover p{
    color: #fff
    
}

.card:hover h2{
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #f2f2f2;
}
.card:nth-child(1):hover{
    background:linear-gradient(45deg,
    rgba(255,28,8,0,7) 0%,
    rgba(255,0,82,0,7) 100%),
        url('file:///E:/Html%20Web%20Design%20Codes/The%20Coffee%20Store/ourservices.html');
    background-size: cover; 
    
    
}

.card:nth-child(2):hover{
    background:linear-gradient(45deg,
    rgba(255,28,8,0,7) 0%,
    rgba(255,0,82,0,7) 100%),
        url('file:///E:/Html%20Web%20Design%20Codes/The%20Coffee%20Store/ourservices.html');
    background-size: cover; 
}




.card:nth-child(3):hover{
    background:linear-gradient(45deg,
    rgba(255,28,8,0,7) 0%,
    rgba(255,0,82,0,7) 100%),
        url('file:///E:/Html%20Web%20Design%20Codes/The%20Coffee%20Store/ourservices.html');
    background-size: cover; 
    
    
}



.card:nth-child(4):hover{
    background:linear-gradient(45deg,
    rgba(255,28,8,0,7) 0%,
    rgba(255,0,82,0,7) 100%),
        url('file:///E:/Html%20Web%20Design%20Codes/The%20Coffee%20Store/ourservices.html');
    background-size: cover; 
    
}

.card:nth-child(5):hover{
    background:linear-gradient(45deg,
    rgba(255,28,8,0,7) 0%,
    rgba(255,0,82,0,7) 100%),
        url('file:///E:/Html%20Web%20Design%20Codes/The%20Coffee%20Store/ourservices.html');
    background-size: cover; 
}


.card:nth-child(6):hover{
    background:linear-gradient(45deg,
    rgba(255,28,8,0,7) 0%,
    rgba(255,0,82,0,7) 100%),
        url('file:///E:/Html%20Web%20Design%20Codes/The%20Coffee%20Store/my%20color.png');
    background-size: cover; 
    
    
    
    /***Responsive****/
    
    
    @media (max-width: 991px)
    {
        .wrapper{
            padding:25px;   
        }
        .wrapper h1{
            font-size: 2.5em;
            font-weight:  600;
            
        }
        .content-box{
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 100%;
            
        }
        .card{
            min-width: 300px;
            margin: 10px auto;
        }
    }
```

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
                 <h1> Our Services </h1>
                <p>Aside from a love of that sweet java, this, Jack Wilson, owner of Radio Bistro </p> 
                <div class="content-box">
                <div class="card">
                    <i class="bx bx-laptop bx-md"></i>
                        <h2>Web App Development</h2>
                        <p>
                        Need help getting started? Check out our business plan templates for guidance. They’re free real-world examples
                        </p>
                </div>
                
                
                
                
                <div class="card">
                    <i class="bx bx-line-chart bx-md"></i>
                        <h2>24/7 Call Center Services</h2>
                        <p>
                        Need help getting started? Check out our business plan templates for guidance. They’re free real-world examples
                        </p>
                    
                 </div>
                    
                <div class="card">
                    <i class="bx bx-mail-send bx-md"></i>
                        <h2>Soical Media Marketing</h2>
                        <p>
                        Need help getting started? Check out our business plan templates for guidance. They’re free real-world examples
                        </p>
                </div>
                   </div>
               
                  <div class="content-box">
                    
                <div class="card">
                    <i class="bx bx-bar-chart-alt bx-md"></i>
                        <h2>Corporate Business </h2>
                        <p>
                        Need help getting started? Check out our business plan templates for guidance. They’re free real-world examples
                        </p>
                </div>
                    
                    
                    
               <div class="card">
                    <i class="bx bx-paint bx-md"></i>
                        <h2>Creative Consultancy</h2>
                        <p>
                        Need help getting started? Check out our business plan templates for guidance. They’re free real-world examples
                        </p>
               </div>
                    
                    
               <div class="card">
                    <i class="bx bx-bar-chart-alt bx-md"></i>
                        <h2>Marketing Services</h2>
                        <p>
                        Need help getting started? Check out our business plan templates for guidance. They’re free real-world examples
                        </p>
               </div>
           </div>
            
            
            
      </div>
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the Op can't udnerstand your answer, then he also wont be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a suficient explaination of your possible solution.  Also note, that you should use a [repro] for validation. Last but not elast, this issue is caused by a typo and as such should not be answered but flagged as such.